# French accents on a PC with US keyboard ?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout, locale

My laptop has a US keyboard, and I need to write some French, with accents.

I know there's a painful way to do it with combinations of the <kbd>alt</kbd> key and <strike>the ascii code</strike> [alt-codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code), but I was wondering if there was an easier way to do it.

PS: Since the question is closed (but the answers no great) I thought I'd add this addendum. Basically, you need to set the keyboard to US International and then you can do accents using `'e` or `'a`; see this link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/97738 [image: screenshot]

**PS: Much much better solution: http://keyxpat.com**.

Comment: Not germane to your question since you're talking about Windows, but Apple's default behavior in iOS (and the latest version of OS X) is to show the various accent forms when you hold down a letter (e.g. "e" offers me è,é,ê,ë,ē,ė, and ę). A nice convenience feature (which I turn off because I usually need character repeat more often than accents :P)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using **[keyxpat](http://www.keyxpat.com)** for about 2 weeks now and I must say that this little piece of software is better than any other options I've tried so far.

Comment: Well 2 years later, I still love it; works great and I'm so used to my US keyboard that I couldn't switch to the French keyboard anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few valid options :

- Use [dead keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key), for instance, [here on SU](https://superuser.com/a/280032/162290) seems to describe it well for Windows 7. [This](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;306560) seems to be the windows doc for it.
- Copy-pasting¹
- Using a french [on-screen keyboard](http://www.osk.com/)²
- Remapping your keyboard to a french layout ([`azerty`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY) for instance)

¹ Enjoy :

```
àáâãäåæ ç èéêë ìíîï ðñ òóôõö ø ùúûüýþÿ
ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆ Ç ÈÉÊË ÌÍÎÏ ÐÑ ÒÓÔÕÖ Ø ÙÚÛÜÝÞß śĺ
```

² That's just googled

Comment: Someone once told me they were able to get accents by using type single-quote in combination with the letter: 'e, "e, and 'a would produce the respective letters with an accent. You know anything about that?

Comment: Yeah, that's called dead keys, incoming bullet.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a Linux desktop, you probably have some kind of [compose key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key) enabled.

If you are on Windows, you can use a software that provides a compose key on. Examples of such softwares can be found on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/64178/114040). If I had to chose, I would go for [AllChars](http://allchars.zwolnet.com/.).

Comment: I use the compose key all the time "comme ça" (c + , = ç)

Answer (score 0):

In MS-Words and some other MS software you get a set of ctrl and shift keys that you can use to access dead keys without having to switch to another keyboard.

I wrote this a little while ago (for my own sake):

http://linux.m2osw.com/diacritics-over-letters-on-ms-windows

Answer (score 0):

Do US keyboards have AltGr? (I'm on a UK keyboard.) I can type áéíóú by pressing AltGr+(aeiou). And as a bonus, the Euro symbol (€) is on the 4 key. I was wondering what the AltGr key did only this morning!